# The exponential map is generally not holomorphic.

Tags: riemann-surfaces, geodesic

> Prove that $\exp_0:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{D}$ is not holomorphic, where $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disk with hyperbolic metric $ds^2=\frac{4dzd\bar{z}}{(1-|z|^2)^2}$.

I am reading Jost's *Compact Riemann Surfaces*. The exponential map is defined by the geodesic, to be more specific
$$
\exp_p:v\mapsto \gamma_{p,v}(1),
$$
where $\|v\|_p$ is suffiently small so the geodisic can be defined in $[0,1]$. Jost claims the exponential map is generally not holomorphic. But I do not know how to prove the problem. Can we just compute the expression of $\exp_0$? Appreciate any help or hint! This part is in p32-33 of the book.

Comment: Not sure, but I’m expecting this exponential to be rotation-equivariant (ie commute with rotations centered at $0$). However, the only such analytic at $0$ maps are linear, and it follows that if it is holomorphic near zero, $\exp_0(z)=z$, which doesn’t work.

Comment: I think the "rotation-equivariant" can be proved by the uniqueness of the geodesic. What do you mean $\exp_0(z)=kz$ doesn't work?

Comment: I mean that $z \longmapsto kz$ cannot be the exponential (because eg it doesn’t produce constant speed curves).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For your concrete question, the canonical coordinate on $\mathbb C$ gives you a complex coordinate on $\mathbb D$ by restriction (recall that the complex coordinates on Riemannian surfaces come from the isothermal coordinates), and then just apply the Liouville's theorem to $\exp$.

For general cases, you can refer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67903).